# How does collision work between a normal object and a blackhole?

Tags: black-holes, conservation-laws, collision

Suppose there is a stationary blackhole from the perspective of a certain observer. Now, suppose a near-light-speed proton is fired towards the blackhole, what would happen after the proton enters the event horizon? Would the blackhole+proton mass begin moving in the same direction the proton's momentum was in? Or would the blackhole remain stationary?

Usually "collision" between objects occur due to repulsive forces such as electrostatic force or Pauli-exclusion principle, would the same still apply for a blackhole? If not, how is this not a violation to the conservation of momentum?

Answer (score 1):

If you make the assumption that, far from any gravitating objects, spacetime asymptotes to Minkowski spacetime, then you can work out that the whole universe has a conserved net energy and momentum.

Now, assume that this net 3-momentum is zero, which can be done by any coordinate transformation that asymptotes to a lorentz transform at infinity.  By this construction, any collision between your proton and your black hole will have to conserve momentum, so yes, the black hole will pick up a small amount of velocity in the direction of the proton's initial motion.  But, note that any collision with a black hole will also produce gravitational radiation, and that radiation will also carry net momentum, which can provide a 'kick' to the final-state black hole.  In the case of colliding binary black holes, the radiation can be directional, and can have enough momentum to accelerate the final state black hole to escape velocity from the galaxy it is in.